# Java running Task<Void> more than once

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, task

I have the following problem: I have a Task:

```
package window;

import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class ClientConnection extends Task<Void> {
    public Socket clientSocket;
    private DataInputStream is = null;
    private DataOutputStream os = null;
    private String messageID;
    private String nodeNameToSend;
    private int layerNumberToSend;
    private String messageTypeToSend;
    private String messageToSend;

    private int portNumber;
    private String name;

    private String soapToString(SOAPMessage message) throws TransformerException {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(new DOMSource((message.getSOAPPart())), new StreamResult(sw));
        return sw.toString();
    }


    public ClientConnection(String name, int portNumber) throws IOException {
        this.name = name;
        this.portNumber = portNumber;
        clientSocket = new Socket(name, portNumber);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("trying to send in separate thread");
        try {
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            SoapWrapper soapWrapper = new SoapWrapper();
            // Creating the message
            MessageWrapper messageWrapper = new MessageWrapper(messageID, nodeNameToSend, layerNumberToSend, messageTypeToSend, messageToSend);
            SOAPMessage msg = soapWrapper.toMessage(messageWrapper);
            out.write(soapToString(msg));
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void setArgs(String messageID, String name, int layerNumber, String messageType, String messageContent) {
        this.messageID = messageID;
        this.nodeNameToSend = name;
        this.layerNumberToSend = layerNumber;
        this.messageTypeToSend = messageType;
        this.messageToSend = messageContent;
    }
}
```

In my JavaFX controller I run it with having a global `ClientConnection cc = new ClientConnection("localhost", 2143);` and then running it somewhere by `new Thread(cc).start();`. Everything works (it works on sockets), `trying to send in separate thread` is printed to the console. But if I want to do this once more (in my case by pressing the button again) it doesnt do anything, `trying to send in separate thread` doesn't get printed. What can I do? I've read that you have to make a new instance of a Thread, but I am doing so, right?

Answer (score 0):

When you say that you have a *global* `ClientConnection`, I assume you mean that you're trying to reuse the same instance of `ClientConnection` for each run. This won't work since `Task` is not reusable [as stated in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html):

> As with FutureTask, a Task is a one-shot class and cannot be reused.

Therefore, you need to make sure that you overwrite the `cc` variable with a new `ClientConnection` for each run (i.e. assign `cc = new ClientConnection(...)` -- in your case this would be the first thing you'd do when you enter the action handler for the button).